# update mongoose document before returning

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous, mongoose

I want to add a property to the returned docs of mongoose query. This property is as well a mongoose query

```
Buildung.find({_id: {$in: user.favorites}}, function (err, buildungs) {
      if (err) { return res.status(400).json({error: err}); }

      const mbuildungs = buildungs.map(buildung => {

        let buildungObject = buildung.toObject();

        const now = new Date();
        Time.findOne({buildung: buildung._id, validFrom: { $lte: Date.parse(now) }}, null,
          {sort: {validFrom: -1}}, (err, time)=> {

            buildungObject.time = time;
          });

        return buildungObject;

      });

      return res.status(200).json({buildungs: mbuildungs})
});
```

The modified object should be returned, but it isnt adding the property `time` to the result.

I've also attempted to work with callback function but I could solve the problem, that I want to achieve.

#### Update

1) Schema

```
// Time
const TimeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
validFrom: {type: Date, required: true},
....
building: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Building', index: true, required: true}

// Building
const BuildingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  .....
  // no relation to timeSchma
})
```

Comment: how are you calling and using it?, the return inside a callback function wont work

Comment: Since `findOne` is a asynchronous call, `return res.status(200).json({buildungs: mbuildungs})` will be call before your `Time.findOne` callback

Comment: Can you update your question to show the schema definitions for both `Buildung` and `Time` models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things that you could fix in your code!

1. Asynchronous functions cannot be called inside a map. You'd need some way to aggregate every `findOne` result - the easiest way out is using the [`async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module. However, I'd personally recommend a Promise-based solution as that looks much cleaner.
2. Mongoose returns its own Object (called `MongooseDocument`) that is decorated with a lot of Mongoose-specific functions, and that makes the return object act differently. To work around this, use [`lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean). This returns a plain object that you can freely modify as you would any other JS object. Using `lean()` also has the additional advantage of [huge performance improvements](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/high-performance-find-query-using-lean-in-mongoose-2/)!

I've included both these changes to your code —

```
const async = require('async');

function findBuildungTime(buildung, done) {
    const now = new Date();
    Time.findOne({ buildung: buildung._id, validFrom: { $lte: Date.parse(now) } }, null, { sort: { validFrom: -1 } })
        .lean()
        .exec((err, time) => {
            buildung.time = time;
            return done(err, buildung);
        });
}

Buildung.find({ _id: { $in: user.favorites } })
    .lean()
    .exec((err, buildungs) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: err });
        }
        async.map(buildungs, findBuildungTime, (err, results) => {
            return res.status(200).json({ buildungs: results })
        });
    });
```

Comment: thats a good hint but what about the async 2nd query? This is also returning just the buildings without the time